# How do I use Bootstrap Glyphicons in 3.0.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, glyphicons

I'm using Glyphicons in Bootstrap. I was calling in the CSS straight from http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css but this has now disappeared and was not recommended.

This apparently coincides with Twitter making the Glyphicons available in the Bootstrap package again. I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0 RC1 or RC2.

My problem: I have no idea how to use the icons in my own hosting...
Seems to me the code is contained within the bootstrap.css (?).
I have uploaded the "fonts" directory but am only getting blank, empty-box icons where there should be proper icons.

Any ideas please? What should be where and how should it be called?

Comment: I think there is a bug in the customiser. If I download the full bootstrap (from the link on the home page) icons display correctly. If I download a customised version I just get small empty boxes.

Comment: looks like it can be root of the problem: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9925

Answer (score 10):

The `bootstrap-glyphicons.css` file seems to have been removed with the final\production Bootstrap 3.0.0. Simply download the zip from http://getbootstrap.com/ and then copy the `dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` file in your css folder. You should then include it in your HTML page as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Glyphicons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS file -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Glyphicon in a H1 tag -->
    <h1>Hello, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> !</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 7):

If you have already put in the fonts directory, calling the icons now would be `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>` instead of `<i class="icon-large icon-pencil"></i>`.

Comment: Yes, I've got the fonts directory in place. And am using that kind of image call. But all I'm getting is blank-box icons. I don't understand it. The only thing different to my knowledge is I'm storing my Bootstrap CSS files in a different folder (/public_html/wp-content/themes/bs3theme/css/rc2/) whereas the fonts are at /public_html/wp-content/themes/bs3theme/fonts/ - but I've changed the file path to that in the bootstrap.css.

Comment: What url did you change in your bootstrap-glyphicons.css? Could be a 404 issue. And I hope you did include that file in your html. You have this line right? `<link href="/public_html/wp-content/themes/bs3theme/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: No, I see no bootstrap-glyphicons.ss included with my Bootstrap 3.0.0 download...The "dist" folder contains a "css" folder that has just four .css files - bootstrap.css (and minified) and bootstrap-theme.css (not mine) (and minified). bootstrap-glyphicons.css is also not in the "fonts" directory.

Comment: Apologies, ignore my last comment. Last push removed the need for glyphicons.css. Just update your css from github and doing `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>` should work. Do note that BS is still RC2 so expect lots of changes.

Comment: Could you get it working? Bs 3 just launched on GitHub gotta update your files

Comment: Yes, @mrkre, I got Glyphicons working with both RC2 and final. I don't know exactly what the issue was but obviously something to do with files and paths. It took uploading the whole of the downloaded Bootstrap contents to get it working; I had previously only uploaded the few things I thought necessary. Now I don't know why my navbar won't toggle, but I suspect that's for another thread. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely file references. Glad to help. Navbar css got changed too..You gotta call <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> now. And some changes to js files too.

Comment: mrkre, I have that navbar code. If you want to look in to my navbar, it's here - http://www.robertandrews.co.uk/ - I'm working on it right now. Thanks.

Comment: We better take this off the comments but you don't have enough points to chat yet. Anyway the link http://www.robertandrews.co.uk/css/rc2/dist/js/bootstrap.js is 404. Nav bar collapse requires the js file to work.

Comment: It was terrible in React project!..., thank you for solution!

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure your fonts folder is placed correctly relative to the .css file: `../fonts`

```
some-root-folder
├--my-css-folder
|  └--bootstrap.min.css
└--fonts
   └--glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

Comment: How could I change the location of the fonts folder?

Answer (score 2):

I followed this post http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application. I don't know if the best way, but Works.