# Glyphicon-shopping-cart don't show iCON

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm designing a website and have a problem. I use the Glyphicon of bootstrap 3.0.0 to design a picture icon "Cart". However,it do not working. My Error like this picture. Please help me!
    Thanks you watching
    This code below:

```
        <!--import CSS-->

        <link  href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link  href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link href="../effect/hover.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../css/effecttext.css" rel ="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../effect/hover-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  ----------------------------------------------------
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

    -------------------------------------------
        <!--Javascript-->
        <script src="main.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why you import bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css? so have you try to inspect the element with browser inspector? Check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310104/how-do-i-use-bootstrap-glyphicons-in-3-0-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310104/how-do-i-use-bootstrap-glyphicons-in-3-0-0)

Comment: Thanks.  I try it but my icon still not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding CDN

Also Remove following lines

```
<link  href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Cart <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's successful. However, I don't understand Why "<link  href="../bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>" not work. Can you explain to me. Please!.